# Calculate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\frac{dx}{x^{2n}+1}}$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-integration

While studying for exam I encountered this problem:
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\frac{dx}{x^{2n}+1}}$=?

As a complex function it has $2n$ singularities : S=$ e^{\frac{\pi i(2k+1)}{2n}}|k\in \mathbb{N}, 0\leq k <2n-1 \brace$

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\frac{dx}{x^{2n}+1}}=\lim_{R\to \infty}\int_{-R}^{R}{\frac{dx}{x^{2n}+1}}$

so using residue theorem :
$\int_{-R}^{R}{\frac{dx}{x^{2n}+1}} + \int_{C^{+}_{R}}{\frac{dz}{z^{2n}+1}} = 2\pi i\sum res(f,s_k)\space$ for  $s_k \in S$ (for $s_k$ in top half plane).

It is easy to see that the second integral vanished as $R \to \infty$.

so: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\frac{dx}{x^{2n}+1}}= 2\pi i\sum res(f,s_k)\space$

but calculating $res(f,s_k$) seems complicated... each singularity is of order 1 to $res(f,s_k) = lim_{z\to s_k}\frac{(z-s_k)}{\Pi(z-s_j)}$

haven't got any further...

thanks